# Show Single Item at a time in Recycler view

Tags: android-recyclerview, wear-os

I'm showing list of items in WearableRecyclerView. As of now I am getting like this
[image]

But I need to show **Single Row(Single Item) in a Page**,Scroll down,then show next Item.

[image]

Any Help to do this in android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by two way.

**option 1:** putting recycler view item width and height both to match_parent.which will cover the screen with with one item at a time and need to scroll for see the next item.

**option 2:** use this [library](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager) which will do the exact thing that you are looking for.

Comment: Option 2 is Working,Option1 is not working in my case.

Comment: Option 2: Library is giving Problem While scrolling.List View Item Content position are misplaced

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet below is used to show one item at a time. After configuration of your recyclerview add the code snippet.

```
PagerSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(nameOfYourRecylerView)
```