# Show single item at a time in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, wear-os

I am working on a WearOS app.  I am using a ListView to show a list of strings.  Right now, the ListView looks like this:

[image]

I want a single row to take up the entire screen.  Once a user swipes up, then Row 2 takes up the entire screen.  Swipe up again and Row 3 takes up the entire screen, etc.  So like this: [image]

I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865309/show-single-item-at-a-time-in-recycler-view), which is exactly what I want to do, but the first method doesn't work and the second method suggests a library, but I don't want to use a library for what seems like a pretty simple task.  I don't want to use RecyclerView.  Thank you for your help.

Here is my XML file for the main activity, which is where the ListView is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_grey"
    android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

    <!-- Change FrameLayout to a RelativeLayour -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/inner_frame_layout_padding"
        app:boxedEdges="all">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Android RecyclerView example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584424/simple-android-recyclerview-example)

Comment: @user8035311 I added the XML.  I am not using a RecyclerView.  Just a ListView because according to the Android tutorials RecyclerView is best for larger lists.  My list will have at maximum 5-10 entries.

Comment: @InsaneCat I actually haven't come across that answer, I'll look at it.

Comment: hope this could help you... https://stackoverflow.com/a/47025423/2404063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (The idea here is to programmatically set the height of the textView to the height of the screen):

1) MnnnnnnnActivity.class:----------

```
public class MnnnnnnnActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView lv;
private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
private String[] s = new String[10];

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout6);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        s[i] = "ROW " + String.valueOf(i + 1);
    }

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MnnnnnnnActivity.this, s);
    lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);

}

public int getScreenHeight() {

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    return displayMetrics.heightPixels;

}
}
```

2) CustomAdapter.class:--------

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private String[] s;
private WeakReference<MnnnnnnnActivity> mActivity;

public CustomAdapter(MnnnnnnnActivity activity1, String[] s) {
    super(activity1.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_view_item, s);
    this.s = s;
    mActivity = new WeakReference<MnnnnnnnActivity>(activity1);

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(mActivity != null) {
        MnnnnnnnActivity activity = mActivity.get();
        if (activity != null) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.tv.setText(s[position]);
            holder.tv.setHeight(activity.getScreenHeight());


        }
    }

    return convertView;

}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;
}

}
```

3) layout6.xml:-----------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lv">
</ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

4) list_view_item.xml:----------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv"
android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="-"
    android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold">
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

5) Note: Although this is tested on phone, the same idea can be used to achieve something similar on a wareable. Also, a better approach would be to set the height of the linearLayout (which contains the textView) to the screen height.

6) Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Do you mind sharing what your gradle file is like? I have com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1 in the gradle file but I am getting an error, so I can't extend AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I'm using v7:27.1.1.

Comment: If your project is for wearable devices then you cannot extend AppCompatActivity, you need to extends WearableActivity.

Comment: Using your solution and another resource online I was able to get the result I wanted.  Thank you!